# Log function returns incorrect values

Tags: c++, math

I have written a small piece of code that takes in 2 numbers `a` and `b` from the user and prints `log(a)/log(b)`. Here is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define int long long int
#define endl '\n'
using namespace std;

signed main(){
    #ifndef FILE_IO
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << log(a)/log(b) << endl;
}
```

Input:

```
571787 83
```

Output:

```
3
```

This works fine. But when I try to obtain the `floor` value of the result in this way:

```
cout << floor(log(a)/log(b)) << endl;
```

It produces:

```
2
```

However,

```
cout << floor(3) << endl;
```

Prints:

```
3
```

What's going on here?

Comment: This is due to floating point precision.  When you output a float, it's rounded to whatever precision is configured for the stream.  This is completely different to taking the floor, where if the value is very near to but less than 3, then it will be truncated to 2.  Perhaps you want `std::round` instead if you want the nearest whole value.  Otherwise, you could add a small "epsilon" value to the result before taking the floor, if you really don't want to round.

Comment: @paddy I also tried typecasting the result (i.e) `cout << floor(double(log(a))/double(log(b))) << endl;`. But still got `2` as the output.

Comment: As a general comment, your `#define endl '\n'` is exceptionally weird and you should remove that line.  This macro will make legitimate code like `std::endl` result in a compilation error instead of correctly resolving a symbol provided by the standard library.  Also, the sooner you drop the habit of using `<bits/stdc++.h>`, the better.  Just stop.  Now is the perfect time.

Comment: Regarding your typecast...   so what?  Do you think that `double` has infinite precision?  No.  It has _more_ precision than `float`, but that's all.  In any case, `std::log` for integer types resolves to a function returning `double` anyway, so unless you're using an older compiler, casting the result like that is equivalent to not casting at all.

Comment: @paddy I use `c++` primarily for competitive programming, where i would be making use of `STL`. Using `bits/stdc++.h>` helps me write code faster. And the same with `#define endl '\n'`. I find `endl` easier to type then `'\n`, and hence, that line :)

Comment: @paddy So what is the solution to this problem? I do not wanna round the result. I just wanna obtain the integral part of the result.

Comment: I already told you.  Add a small value to account for floating point precision error.  The amount may depend on the size of your inputs.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon and also remember that competitive programming teaches bad habits.  If you're doing it to become a better programmer, you're fooling yourself.

Comment: By the way, what do you consider as the integral part of: 2.1, 2.3, 2.7, 2.89, 2.9, 2.999, 2.999999999999999999 ....?  Where do you draw the line?  Wherever you draw the line, take the difference and that is essentially the minimum epsilon you need to use.  Or you can just round, cos honestly it sounds like you actually want to round even though you don't think you do.

Comment: `log(571787) / log(83)` must return 3, and the integral part of 3 is 3. However, as u mentioned, the floating point precision causes 2.99999 to be returned instead of 3. I'll try implementing `epsilon` and get back to u. Thx for helping :)

Comment: @paddy The `epsilon` method is too complex to be implemented for such an easy problem. Instead, I typecasted the result of `log` to a `float` in order to reduce the precision and guess what, it worked!

Comment: It's "too complex" to just add, say `0.0001`?  And using `float` "fixes" this?  hahah, well, I wish you all the best in your competitive programming adventures and future career.

Comment: @paddy Nah not that lol. Why do i have to implement templates as given here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon to solve such easy problems? And does using `float` cause problems? Plus, why do u say that using `bits/stdc++.h` a bad practice?

Comment: Let me answer your question with another question: Why have you not specified the actual problem you need to solve?  In particular, is there always expected to be an integer result?  If so, then why on earth are you not using an integer-based approach, such as dividing by the base in a loop and counting how many times it takes to reach a value of 0 or 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230294/discussion-between-sushil-and-paddy).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)